# Vimperator: Follow link with number in the text

Tags: keyboard-navigation, vimperator

I use Vimperator, but one thing I struggle with is being able to efficiently select and navigate a link that has (or is) just a number. This happens quite a lot in various generated web pages  use where the links are numerical or are dates.

Using just `f` to enter hints mode doesn't work, as typing a number will naturally send you to that hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m not very familiar with Vimperator, but in its fork and further development – Pentadactyl, you can use backslash to make following digits be treated as link inner text, not number. I. e. use `f\21` to narrow the search to the links with text starting from / contains¹ `21`.

---

<sup>¹ Depending on your preferences, `'hintmatching'` option to be precise.</sup>